# Cómo crear un div a partir de createElement("div"); dentro de un div existente en mi pagina

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

quiero crear un `div` con una id que vaya variando mediante un contador dentro de una división ya creada dentro del cuerpo de mi **html**. Se trata de un botón que va creando tareas dentro de un `div` pero solo las crea dentro del `body` al hacer `appenChild()`.

Es decir al obtener el elemento del `dom` del `div` de mi página falla. Como os digo `document.division.appendChild(divNota)` falla, pero si añado `document.body.appendChild(divNota)` funcionaría perfectamente añadiendo la división al `body`. Quería añadir la nota dentro del `div` `division`.

Muchas gracias.

```
var contador=0;

alert(contador);

function creartag(){

    var contenido = prompt("Añade la nota:","");

     alert(contador);
      contador++;
    alert(contador);
    var iddd ="tarea"+contador;

    alert(iddd);

    var divNota = document.createElement("div");
    divNota.setAttribute("id",iddd);
    divNota.setAttribute("class","tags");


    var division = document.getElementById(division_bloque_principal_sesion_iniciada);

    document.division.appendChild(divNota); 


    divNota.innerHTML = contenido;

  }
```

Comment: `document.division`? Solo debería ser `division.appendChild(myDiv)`

Comment: Tras probar un rato di con el fallo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dice @RimuruTempest, estás referenciando mal el elemento al usar de nuevo `document`.

Además de eso, me permito algunas recomendaciones de optimización y de seguridad:

1. Es mejor crear la refencia `division` fuera de la función, de lo contrario estarías molestando al `document` cada vez para lo mismo.
2. Yo evitaría usar ids tan largossss como `division_bloque_principal_sesion_iniciada`
3. Quiero llamar la atención sobre [una nota sobre la seguridad en MDN con respecto al uso de `innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Advierte que el uso de `innerHTML` puede ser una puerta abierta a ataques de *cross-site scripting*. Haciendo caso a esa nota, es preferible usar [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent), es más seguro y más rápido. El código más abajo lo usa.

   > Cuando solo tratamos con texto, es recomendable no usar innerHTML,
   >   sino Node.textContent, que no interpretará la cadena pasada como HTML,
   >   sino como texto plano.

```js
var contador = 0;
//alert(contador);
  var division = document.getElementById("division_bloque_principal_sesion_iniciada");


function creartag() {
  var contenido = prompt("Añade la nota:", "");
  //alert(contador);
  contador++;
  //alert(contador);
  var iddd = "tarea" + contador;
  //alert(iddd);
  var divNota = document.createElement("div");
  divNota.setAttribute("id", iddd);
  divNota.setAttribute("class", "tags");
  division.appendChild(divNota);
  divNota.textContent = contenido;

}
```

```html
<div id="division_bloque_principal_sesion_iniciada"></div>
<button onclick="creartag()">Crear</button>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, aplicare los consejos con mucho gusto